# Do Flurry event parameters values must be strings?

Tags: ios, flurry, flurry-analytics

So what are the accepted types of values for event parameters in Flurry?
I can only find NSString examples, but there seems to be no explicit info in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Flurry event parameter key and values need to be strings of up to 255 characters. The documentation for Obj-C and Swift may be found here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/events/ios/#tab=0

You can find specific uses within the sample app found here:

https://github.com/flurry/YodeliOSApp

Comment: Could you provide link to docs that defines types of event parameters values?

Comment: There are no preset 'types' of parameters. The parameters are key/value pairs that are defined by the app developer.

Comment: Flurry should define in docs what values are supported by sdk/panel.